# WSO2 DAS with MongoDB

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Is it possible to setup MongoDB as the analytic datasource in WSO2 DAS? I saw DAS support cassandra , HBase in analytics-datasources.xml script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done a PR to support MongoDB in DAS. It is already included in the master branch, you can take a look at these PRs:

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/pull/225

And here:

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-data/pull/133

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks. How I can install this support MongoDB in a working EI 6.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, WSO2 Data Analytics Server (DAS) does not support MongoDB. However, we have written DAS in such a way that, it is easy to setup other databases such as MongoDB as your analytics data source.

The procedure is pretty simple and you just need to implement [AnalyticsRecordStore](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/blob/master/components/analytics-core/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/datasource/core/rs/AnalyticsRecordStore.java) interface. It is well documented and I hope you can easily understand it. Additionally, I would like to point out 
[CassandraAnalyticsRecordStore](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/blob/master/components/analytics-data-connectors/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.cassandra/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/datasource/cassandra/CassandraAnalyticsRecordStore.java) which is the Cassandra implementation of the AnalyticsRecordStore interface.

P.S. If you manage to implement the AnalyticsRecordStore interface for MongoDB, you are more than welcome to send a Pull Request to [carbon-analytics](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics) repository.